# Is there a difference between ”をなる” and ”なっていて”

Tags: verbs, adjectives, particle-を

I was understanding なる verb today, as well as adjectives.
I know the fact that adjective + verb can be mixed together with each other. So, I came across an example stating:

> "家が赤くなっています" (House is becoming red). Over here House is the subject and 
>    赤い(Red) is the adjective which is being conjugated with なる form to become 赤くなっています。

However, won't it be better to say the same when we change it to：

> 家が赤をなっています (house is becoming red). As in this statement, the House is
>   the subject on which the noun (赤) is acting upon by becoming (なっています).

- I can't find any similar question on the web; is my 2nd sentence of using を is grammatically correct?
- Will it make any difference in meaning and grammatically,if I use Noun+Verb rather than Adj+Verb.?

Thanks :)

Comment: なる is intransitive i.e. cannot work on objects using を. So with a noun you need に -> 赤になっています

Comment: @mic, ありがと, I haven't studied about なる being intransitive. Coming back, so, it has to necessarily use adj+Naru, To make the sentence grammatical? So, what about using になる in this case. Will the meaning change, when using it with  に rather than が?

Comment: Concerning what you are talking about here. <adverb>なる or <noun>になる, or other verb-form (なっている)/tense(なった).

Comment: I mean difference between (noun)になる and (Adverb)なる. 
Let's say in 家が赤くなっています and 家が赤になっています

Answer (score 3, accepted):

を marks a direct object.  This is a noun that has something done to it.  For example, it can be thrown, kicked, eaten, etc.  Transitive verbs (verbs were something is done to something else) are what take を in this case.

`To become` is a verb that does not take a direct object.  It is an intransitive verb, meaning it happens on its own.

In English, some verbs are exclusively transitive (kick, throw, etc.).  Some verbs can transitive and intransitive forms (`I open the door.` [transitive] `The door opened.` [intransitive]).  Finally, some verbs are exclusively intransitive (to become.)

に, as discussed previously can mark the result of a change.  なる is a verb that indicates change, and as such requires that に be used in the formation.  The に marks what the final result of the transformation/change is becoming.

50% of the time, you will see `noun + になる`, and occasionally, the other 50% of the time you will see `adverb + なる` (なくなる, くらくなる, etc.).

---

**EDIT:**

Looking at the comment feed on the question, you ask for the following distinction:

> I mean difference between (noun)になる and (Adverb)なる.

(noun)になる modifies another noun.  The subject noun changes or becomes something else (as marked by に)

(Adverb)なる is slightly different, but it usually denotes a change in state, whether it be atmospheric (socially or otherwise), or physical (living to dead, for example).  While exceptions exist, this form is generally more subtle.

> So can you please tell me, whether the meaning would change and make a difference between (noun)になる and (Adverb)なる.? E.g. Let's say in 家が赤くなっています and 家が赤になっています

Using に：

家が赤**に**なっています。 Is saying that the house is becoming red (the noun).  You are changing its color to red (via paint, stucco, or some other means).  This is a stronger, starker change than what you'd get with the adverb form.

Using the adverb:

家が**赤く**なっています。 Is saying that the house (potentially of its own accord) is becoming red.  It could be a trick of the light, it could be that its rusting.  This change is typically more gradual, but it can also be used to denote that you are affecting a change on it as well.

Both can be used in this sentence:

> 青が大嫌いだから私はペンキを買いました。家が赤(く/に)なっています。

One indicates that the house is becoming red on its own (adverb), the other indicates that the house is changing as a result of something you are actively doing (に).  Which form you use will depend on how much you focus on your actions, as opposed to the changes that are happening to the house.

Comment: So can you please tell me, whether the meaning would change and make a difference between (noun)になる and (Adverb)なる.?
E.g. Let's say in 家が赤くなっています and 家が赤になっています

Comment: ありがと you help a lot !